# Show content on and off with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want to do is, show a some content on and off using css or javascript. not jQuery, the reason is I'm having some jQuery clases and the script below doesnt render. Spent hours trying to find the reason, but couldnt.

I have 2 questions.

**Question 1**

Can someone help me to translate this to Javascript. A working fiddle here : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/En4Ka/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change',function(){
var val = $(this).val();
$('div').hide();
$('.' + val).css('display','block'); }).change();
});
```

**Question 2**

Is there a way to find what's going on with website's scripts and how they render. Because Im find it hard to see whats blocking the above script. Thanks

Comment: Your selectors are far too general. There's no way you could want to hide ALL the `div` elements on a page.

Comment: each div has its class. Did you see the fiddle. Will that help?

Comment: That's fair enough, but `div`s are used for a lot of things. If you have even one `div` whose class name is not in the `select` then your page will not work.

Comment: If you mean you see no contents for "Landlords", that's because you don't have any divs if class `land_claims`.

Comment: No. Im saying nothing works because due to a clash with another script. i cant find which script it is coz im editing someone elses website.

Comment: So many lines of code can be thrown out with this. Why make so many divs? also, you can just use .show() instead of .css(...

Comment: Would you mind posting a code?

Comment: Responding to your question 2: I always use Google Chrome's developer tools, it has a console where errors are shown, and you can check all elements in your webpage and which resources are loaded. That might help you. I know it is annoying to find no error after hours of searching, but I would recommend to find the **cause** of the bug and not try to hide the **symptoms** somewhere else. Otherwise, you will probably run again and again into the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1 try this :)

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('div[class$=claims]').hide();
    $('.' + val).show();
}).change();
```

and 2 - use webinspector (press F12) in chrome or firebug in firefox